# Custom field set - how to move Delete button (or prevent deletes)?

Tags: custom-fields, delete

Users are 'accidentally' deleting custom field sets because (so they claim) the 'Edit' button and the 'Delete' button are too close together after clicking the custom field set tab.  So is it possible to move the delete button to the right?  One solution is to disable the ability to delete custom field sets but that doesn't see possible - we are using ACLs that only allow 'Edit'.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bit of CSS (either in your CMS theme or in a custom CSS file you define in **Administer menu » System Settings » Resource URLs** to move the buttons further apart.

Comment: This is the route we've taken in several places, I also usually add some color or sizing to make the more 'desirable' button more prominent.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the delete option in an extension, using the buildForm hook: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/ or hiding it in a jQuery script.